# Flutter not scrolling back

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, dart

CODE

```
 Widget getMainListViewUI() {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SizedBox();
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: AppBar().preferredSize.height +
                  MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
                  24,
              bottom: 62 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
            ),
            itemCount: data.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              widget.animationController.forward();
              return AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: widget.animationController,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return TutorialsListWidget(
                      animation: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
                              parent: widget.animationController,
                              curve: Interval((1 / data.length) * index, 1.0,
                                  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))),
                      animationController: widget.animationController,
                      Count: data.length,
                      Heading: data[index]['Heading'],
                      Index: index);
                },
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

This is my Listview code and it works fine when it comes to scrolling down. I can scroll smoothly till the bottom of the screen and it gives me no problem but if i try to scroll back (Scroll Up), it forcefully goes to the top without scrolling.

Example :
Scrolling Down : 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
Scrolling Up : 10-9-2-1

Its forcefully going to the top of the Listview. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime debug build is slow.
Try with release build.